# After a minute of operation one of the 4 threads breaks GStreamer Python

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I read the stream from several cameras at the same time, if there are 2 of them, everything works without problems. If I read stream from 4 cameras at once, then after a minute of work one of the 4 streams crashes (freezes ?). If I use self.source.set_property('latency', 0) parameter different from 0, then the streams do not crash, but some of the images get broken. Already broke my head with this problem.
Please help

```
# cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False
from enum import Enum
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep
from itertools import cycle
from collections import deque

import numpy as np
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst  # noqa, liberty on Cython, so class Gst exist

from logging import getLogger



class StreamMode(Enum):
    INIT_STREAM = 1
    SETUP_STREAM = 1
    READ_STREAM = 2


class StreamCommands(Enum):
    FRAME = 1
    ERROR = 2
    HEARTBEAT = 3
    RESOLUTION = 4
    STOP = 5


class GStreamCapture(Process):

    def __init__(self, link, queue, name='gstreamer', skip_part_of_frame=0):
        """
        Initialize the stream capturing process
        link - rstp link of stream
        stop - to send commands to this process
        outPipe - this process can send commands outside
        """

        super().__init__(name=name)
        if skip_part_of_frame < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'uncorrected value {skip_part_of_frame} for skip_part_of_frame')
        self.skip_part_of_frame = cycle(range(skip_part_of_frame + 1))
        self.streamLink = link
        self.stop = False
        self.queue = queue
        self._thread_queue = deque()
        self.currentState = StreamMode.INIT_STREAM
        self.pipeline = None
        self.source = None
        self.decode = None
        self.convert = None
        self.sink = None
        self.num_unexpected_tot = 40
        self.unexpected_cnt = 0
        self.logger = getLogger('gstreamer')
        self._log_time = time()
        self._frame_counter = 0

    def send_thread(self):
        while True:
            if self._thread_queue:
                im = self._thread_queue.popleft()
                if next(self.skip_part_of_frame) == 0 and not self.queue.full():
                    self._frame_counter += 1
                    self.queue.put_nowait(im)
            sleep(.001)

    def new_buffer(self, sink, _):
        sample = sink.emit("pull-sample")
        arr = self.gst_to_opencv(sample)
        self._thread_queue.append(arr)
        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK

    @staticmethod
    def gst_to_opencv(sample):
        buf = sample.get_buffer()
        caps = sample.get_caps()
        # self.logger.info Height, Width and Format
        # self.logger.info(caps.get_structure(0).get_value('format'))
        # self.logger.info(caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height'))
        # self.logger.info(caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width'))
        arr = np.ndarray(
            (caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height'),
             caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width'),
             3),
            buffer=buf.extract_dup(0, buf.get_size()),
            dtype=np.uint8)
        return arr

    def run(self):
        Gst.init(None)
        t = Thread(target=self.send_thread)
        t.start()
        # Create the empty pipeline
        self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
            'rtspsrc name=m_rtspsrc ! rtph264depay name=m_rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 name=m_avdech264 !'
            ' videoconvert name=m_videoconvert ! videorate name=m_videorate ! appsink name=m_appsink')

        # source params
        self.source = self.pipeline.get_by_name('m_rtspsrc')
        self.source.set_property('latency', 0)
        self.source.set_property('location', self.streamLink)
        self.source.set_property('protocols', 'tcp')
        self.source.set_property('retry', 50)
        self.source.set_property('timeout', 50)
        self.source.set_property('tcp-timeout', 5000000)
        self.source.set_property('drop-on-latency', 'true')

        # decode params
        self.decode = self.pipeline.get_by_name('m_avdech264')
        self.decode.set_property('max-threads', 2)
        self.decode.set_property('output-corrupt', 'false')

        # convert params
        self.convert = self.pipeline.get_by_name('m_videoconvert')

        # framerate parameters
        self.framerate_ctr = self.pipeline.get_by_name('m_videorate')
        self.framerate_ctr.set_property('max-rate', 50)
        self.framerate_ctr.set_property('drop-only', 'true')

        # sink params
        self.sink = self.pipeline.get_by_name('m_appsink')

        # Maximum number of nanoseconds that a buffer can be late before it is dropped (-1 unlimited)
        # flags: readable, writable
        # Integer64. Range: -1 - 9223372036854775807 Default: -1
        self.sink.set_property('max-lateness', 500000000)

        # The maximum number of buffers to queue internally (0 = unlimited)
        # flags: readable, writable
        # Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 0
        self.sink.set_property('max-buffers', 1)

        # Drop old buffers when the buffer queue is filled
        # flags: readable, writable
        # Boolean. Default: false
        self.sink.set_property('drop', 'true')

        # Emit new-preroll and new-sample signals
        # flags: readable, writable
        # Boolean. Default: false
        self.sink.set_property('emit-signals', True)

        # # sink.set_property('drop', True)
        # # sink.set_property('sync', False)

        # The allowed caps for the sink pad
        # flags: readable, writable
        # Caps (NULL)
        caps = Gst.caps_from_string(
            'video/x-raw, format=(string){BGR, GRAY8}; video/x-bayer,format=(string){rggb,bggr,grbg,gbrg}')
        self.sink.set_property('caps', caps)

        if not self.source or not self.sink or not self.pipeline or not self.decode or not self.convert:
            self.logger.debug("Not all elements could be created.")
            self.stop = True

        self.sink.connect("new-sample", self.new_buffer, self.sink)

        # Start playing
        ret = self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
            self.logger.debug("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.")
            self.stop = True

        # Wait until error or EOS
        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        while True:

            if self.stop:
                self.logger.error('Stopping CAM Stream by main process')
                break

            message = bus.timed_pop_filtered(10000, Gst.MessageType.ANY)
            # self.logger.info "image_arr: ", image_arr

            if message:
                if message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
                    err, debug = message.parse_error()
                    self.logger.error("Error received from element %s: %s" % (
                        message.src.get_name(), err))
                    self.logger.debug("Debugging information: %s" % debug)
                    break
                elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
                    self.logger.warning("End-Of-Stream reached.")
                    break
                elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.STATE_CHANGED:
                    if isinstance(message.src, Gst.Pipeline):
                        old_state, new_state, pending_state = message.parse_state_changed()
                        self.logger.debug("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s." %
                                          (old_state.value_nick, new_state.value_nick))
                else:
                    self.logger.debug(f"Unexpected message received {message.type}")
                    self.unexpected_cnt = self.unexpected_cnt + 1
                    if self.unexpected_cnt == self.num_unexpected_tot:
                        break
            if time() - self._log_time > 30:
                self.logger.warning(f"Camera {self.streamLink} reads with {int(self._frame_counter / 30)} fps")
                self.framerate_ctr.set_property('max-rate', int(self._frame_counter / 30) + 2)
                if not self._frame_counter:
                    print()
                    break
                self._frame_counter = 0
                self._log_time = time()
            sleep(1)
        self.logger.warning('terminating cam pipe')
        self.queue.put(None)
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

I tried playing around with the parameters, but couldn't find the right ones. I am not very familiar with gstreamer, it was inherited.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).